# eXo Platform - addon management not downloading catalog

Tags: docker, tomcat

I'm trying to implement an eXo Platform site but I'm struggling. I use the exo-community Docker image and I am behind a corporate proxy. I followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://exo-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eXo_addons.html#using-the-add-ons-manager-behind-a-proxy-server) and the `CATALINA_OPTS` are well recorded with my proxy information when I echo them.

I'm trying to install the `exo-jdbc-driver-mysql` addon with the command :
`docker exec -u 0 -it test4exoplatform_exo_1 ./addon install exo-jdbc-driver-mysql`. But it stops at this moment and never download the addon :

```
exo_1  | # eXo add-ons installation start ...
exo_1  | # ------------------------------------ #
exo_1  | # installing add-ons from EXO_ADDONS_LIST environment variable:
exo_1  | eXo Add-ons Manager v1.0.2
exo_1  | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here the content of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  exo:
    image: exoplatform/exo-community:4.3
    environment:
      EXO_ADDONS_LIST: exo-jdbc-driver-mysql //I tried as well like this, but same result
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - exo_data:/srv/exo
      - exo_logs:/var/log/exo

volumes:
  exo_data:
    external:
      name: exo_data
  exo_logs:
    external:
      name: exo_logs
```

Comment: Did you succeed to install the driver addon ?